# Как поменять местами биты в байте?

Tags: ассемблер

Доброго времени суток, прошу помощи.
Необходимо в числе 120 поменять местами биты     (0 и 1, 2 и 3, 4 и 7, 5 и 6)
. Вообще не представляю как это можно сделать.

Comment: Так начните с какой-нибудь толковой книжки или статьи, описывающей битовые операции. Для начала - как установить и сбросить нужный бит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если изначально число в `al`, то можно так:

```
    mov ah,al
    shr ah,1
    and ah,055H
    shl al,1
    and al,0AAH
    or  al,ah
    mov bl,al
    shl bl,2
    and bl,0C0H
    mov ah,al
    shr ah,2
    and ah,030H
    and al,00FH
    or  al,ah
    or  al,bl
```

На C/C++ это выглядит так:

```
unsigned char c = 120;
unsigned char x = ((c<<1)&0xAA)|((c>>1)&0x55);
unsigned char y = ((x<<2)&0xC0)|((x>>2)&0x30)|(x&0x0F);
```

Результат в `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Напишу алгоритм схематически, а уже Вы переводите его в целевой ассемблер.

Подобные перемещения реализуем так - выделяем бит, двигаем, прикладываем.

Так как я не знаю целевого ассемблера, буду писать на условном. Пусть в регистре A исходное число, B - результат, C - воспомогательный

```
mov A, 120 // исходное число
mov B, 0 // занулим результат. Поехали
// биты нумеруем по стандарту 765432110
// двигаем 0 на 1 место
mov C, A // скопируем себе А временно
AND C, 0x01 // выделяем только один нужный бит
SHL C,0x1 //  сдвинем на нужную позицию
OR B,C // добавим к результату
// двигаем 1 на 0 место
mov C, A // 
AND C, 0x02 // здесь маска другая 
SHR C,1 //  и двигаем в другую сторону
OR B,C //
```

и так продолжаем двигать остальные биты. Конечно, учитывая, что нужно обменять 0-1 и 2-3, их можно двигать одновременно, просто маска будет 0x5 и 0xA

Если в задаче нет ошибки и обменять нужно именно попарно биты, то это можно сделать кодом выше, просто применив маски 0x55 и 0xAA